# IndexedDB "updates" every browser restart and erases data

Tags: firefox, indexeddb, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wrote a Firefox WebExtension that downloads data files from a website and uses IndexedDB to store/update the data.  The `.SQLite` file that is created is ~2GB in size.  Whenever I restart Firefox, the extension executes the `onupgradeneeded` event, even though I always use version "1".  I create the database object stores and indexes in that event, so *all my data ends up getting deleted*.

**The only time this doesn't happen is when I close Firefox while the data is being downloaded or stored.**  The next time I start Firefox, it does not execute the event (as should be the case).  It then continues to update the database as it was programmed to do.

I installed the SQLite Manager extension in hopes that I could identify something causing the issue to the database, but nothing was obvious to me.

Here is part of my background script:

```
init().then(fetchData).then(addData).catch(dberror);

function init() {
    req = indexedDB.open("db", 1);

    req.onupgradeneeded = e => {
        var name;
        var key;

        console.log("Upgrading database...", e.oldVersion, e.newVersion);
        db = e.currentTarget.result;
        var store = db.createObjectStore("db", { keyPath: "KEY" });
        db.createObjectStore("version", { keyPath: "version" });

        for (name in indexes) {
            key = ...
            store.createIndex(name, key);
        };
    };

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        req.onsuccess = e => {
            db = e.currentTarget.result;
            db.onerror = dberror;
            var cursor = db.transaction("MECs").objectStore("MECs").index("STATUS_DATE").openCursor(null, 'prev');
            cursor.onsuccess = e => {
                if (e.target.result) {
                    lastMod = e.target.result.key;
                    fileYear = lastMod.getFullYear();
                }
                else lastMod = new Date(startingfileYear, 0);
                resolve(lastMod);
            }
            cursor.onerror = reject;
        };
        req.onerror = e => {
            dberror(e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

function fetchData(param) {
    // Get data based on the param and return it
    return fetchFile(filename);
}

function addData(data) {
    var trans = db.transaction("db", "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore("db");
    var req;
    var n = 0;
    var data2 = [];
    var addPromise;

    trans.onerror = event => console.log("Error! Error! ", event.target.error);
    trans.onabort = event => console.log("Abort! Abort! ", event.target.error);

    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        //process data here
        data2 = ...
    });

    (function storeRegData(n) {
        var row = data[n];
        if (!row) return;
        req = store.put(row);
        req.onsuccess = event => {
            numUpdated++;
            storeRegData(++n);
        }
        req.onabort = event => console.log("Abort! Abort! ", event.target.error);
        req.onerror = event => console.log("Error! Error! ", event.target.error);
    })(0);   // I'm storing one row at a time because the transaction is failing when I queue too many rows.

    addPromise = fetchData(data2).then(
        response => {
            var trans2 = db.transaction("db", "readwrite");
            var store2 = trans2.objectStore("db");
            var req2;
            response.forEach(row => {
                req2 = store2.put(row);
                req2.onsuccess = event => numUpdated++;
                req2.onerror = console.log;
            });
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => trans2.oncomplete = e => resolve(response));
        },
        console.log)
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => trans.oncomplete = e => {
        if (noMoreData)
            resolve(addPromise);
        else if (moreData)
            resolve( addPromise.then(fetchData).then(addData) );
    });
}
```

And here is my manifest

```
{
"author": "Name",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Extension",
"description": "Extension",
"version": "3.0",

"applications": {
  "gecko": {
    "strict_min_version": "50.0",
    "id": "myID",
    "update_url": "https://update.me"
  }
},

"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "js/background.js"
  ]
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "https://match.me/*" ],
    "js": [
      "script.js"
    ],
    "css": [
      "style.css"
    ]
  }
],

"icons": {
  "48": "icon.png"
},

"options_ui": {
  "page": "options.html"
},

"page_action": {
  "browser_style": true,
  "default_icon": {
    "19": "icon-19.png",
    "38": "icon-38.png"
  },
  "default_title": "Extension",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"permissions": [
  "https://web.address/*",
  "downloads",
  "notifications",
  "storage",
  "tabs",
  "webRequest",
  "webNavigation"
],

"web_accessible_resources": [
  "pictures.png"
]
}
```

Why does Firefox think the database is at version 0 when I restart the browser?  I can use the stored data after I download it, so why does it overwrite it on every restart?  I could possibly do a workaround where I only create the store and indexes on extension installation or update, but that's not a solution to the actual issue.

**UPDATE:** I tried the following to no avail -

1. Close the database and re-open after storing each data file
2. Create a new object store for each data file

**UPDATE 2:**  It appears this is related to a storage issue.  Apparently, 2GB is the storage limit for non-persistent storage.  In Firefox you can by-pass this by making the storage persistent with the following command:
`indexedDB.open("db", { version: 1, storage: "persistent" })`

See the bugzilla report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1331618).

Unfortunately, when run from a background page, the popup asking for confirmation is not handled, so you can never acknowledge it.  Supposedly, when Firefox 56 comes out, you'll be able to use the "unlimitedStorage" permission, which will by-pass the confirmation popup, so it should work from the background page.

**Update 3:**  So it looks like the limit is actually ~1.5 GB.  I just spent over a week re-coding the extension to create and use a different database for each year of data, making each database no larger than 150 MB.  And still `onupgradeneeded` executes when I restart the browser and wipes all my data.  If, however, I limit the total amount of data in all the databases to the above limit, it works.  Unfortunately, I'm still in the same boat.

Does no one have any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension?

Comment: I agree I didn't put enough code in there.  From my perspective there wasn't anything else that was really relevant to the problem, but how would you know that?  So from the thousands of lines of code, I just added those that were directly related to database interactions.  I included the manifest as well.

Comment: @Makyen  As for what's shown in the browser console, I obviously get what I output to it. When it's "upgrading", that's `Upgrading database... 0 1`, with "0" and "1" being the old and new database version numbers. When it's downloading files, I indicate that, as well as the number of rows that get updated in the database. But there is nothing that gets outputted to the console without a direct command from me (i.e. there are no errors or other information to output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the updates to my question, there appears to be a limit of ~1.5GB for the "default" storage of indexedDB.  Changing the storage to "persistent" will remove that limit.  Because persistent storage currently requires user input, however, the database has to be opened from a window that can handle a UI response.

This can be done from the background script by creating a new window with `browser.window.create()` and opening the database from there.  There are security restrictions that prevent inline scripts from running in the new page, so I had to link to local javascript files for that (i.e. `<script src="db.js"></script>`.  I think you can also change the content security policy with a manifest instruction, but I didn't do that.

Hopefully, the `unlimitedStorage` permission will be supported in **Firefox 56**, which will remove the popup, allowing a persistent database to be created/accessed directly from the background script.